# Dynamic Code Loading on Android platform

Tags: unity, android, oculus

I have read a few articles on `Dynamic code Loading` for the Android platform

- [Dynamic Code Loading in Android](https://kalpeshchandora12.medium.com/dynamic-code-loading-in-android-dea83ba3bc85)
- [Load DEX file dynamically on Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349097/load-dex-file-dynamically-on-android-5-0)
- [Custom Class Loading in Dalvik](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html)

All these talk about the how to achieve it using `DexClassLoader` with Java.

I'm not quite sure about how to get this done with Unity / C# , the target would be Oculus Quest 2, which presumably comes installed with Android 10.

Can dynamic code loading be achieved in Unity when building for Oculus Quest 2? if not is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you share any context about what game feature you're trying to implement with this? There may be a Unity-idiomatic way to achieve that end goal.

Comment: @DMGregory End goal being 1. keeping the base apk, size small and loading feature sets dynamically based on the user profile. 2. There would be lots of minor changes to the code during the initial phases, and do a full apk build for each is cumbersome. So just updating relevant parts of the code would be beneficial here.